# What is the oxidation state of the two tin bonds in the below structure?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

[image: Tin Compound]

I understand that typically, ethylene as a ligand has a neutral charge and would not contribute to the oxidation state of the transition metal bound to it. However, I am seeing conflicting information as I try to determine the oxidation state of each of the tin centers. The Ar group is anionic and the tin would thus be at least Sn(I). However, I am seeing claims that ethylene as a bridging ligand acts as an anionic ligand instead of a neutral ligand. Could anyone help/teach me how I should go about determining the oxidation states of each of the tin centers?

Comment: The language here is confusing. Oxidation state is a concept to aid our understanding of chemistry, not some fundamental property of nature. A tin center doesn't walk around with an oxidation state, so there is no meaning in what you can claim it to be.

You should split this system in half for symmetry and look at the ligands. There should be 3 anionic ligands.